# How to send a game from @gamee telegram bot and track the records and scores

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

i have a telegram bot that i want to send games from @gamee telegram bot and track records but i'm not quite sure how to do that.
I usually program my bots with `python` and the `PyTelegramBotAPI` library.
Is there any way to do this?
I want it to be in Python btw.
any suggestions would be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to build [Telegram Bot Games](https://core.telegram.org/bots/games) using only Python. As they should be written in HTML5 (6th word of documentation) for UI (Frontend).

And when user presses `Play button` - Telegram opens built-in browser to show HTML5 page. So even PyGame will not help here.

The only way Python can help - is to build Backend for that game.

Comment: yes i know that but i don't want to build a game with python. i want to build a bot with python which can send a prepared games from gamee bot and track the records and scores. like forwarding the games in gamee but it cant forward the games and track the records. i tried sending a game to my robot and see the response. it turns out that the bot wont consider the message as a valid message and it didn't respond to that.

Comment: @Amir_DA you can’t do that, because you need to have your own games to control them